# Why am I unable to install eclipse hat am I doing wrong?

Tags: java, eclipse

please help me with this problem, it is very frustrating.
I downloaded adt bundle for 64x pc. My os is Windows 7 64x pc. First it gave me an error that it could not find jre. Okay I took jre from Program Files and copied that into the adt bundle directory then it will tell me FAILED TO LOAD JNI SHARED LIBRARY. 
I downloaded Java jre and jdk from Oracle.com for 64x and none of them will even run on click? 
Its crazy, everything is 64x what am I doing wrong?
Please help

Comment: No idea what you're doing. First, you need to JDK installed and not the JRE. Second, you do not need to copy that JDK to anywhere.

Comment: JDK installer won't run. How do I solve that issue?

Comment: And what is the error when it fails to install JDK?

Comment: I don't know why. I clicked on it and nothing happened. What can be a possible cause?

Comment: Hm, are you sure you downloaded JDK for windows? Is it .exe file?

Comment: jdk-8-windows-x64.exe this is the name of the file

Comment: Try jdk 7 at least. I just can't believe that nothing appears when you run that .exe.

Comment: I downloaded jdk 7. Now there's an error appearing. Can it be because my username directory in Widnows 7 has non latin characters in it?

Comment: Definitely, it is not even recommended to have white-spaces in the path to Java

Comment: PRoblem solved. The issue wat with the directory.

Answer (score 0):

You need to give the javax.exe path in eclipse.ini file

for example

```
-vm
C:\Java\JDK\1.6\bin\javaw.exe
```

[eclipse wiki](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse.ini#-vm_value%3a_Windows_Example)

Comment: The thing is that I am somehow unable to run the JDK installation file. It won't run on click.

Comment: @OlegArsyonov you do not have jdk installed?